# Creating x number of random date of births and x number of dates that are at least 18 years after corresponding date of birth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have created a list of random date of births, now using that I would like to create a list of random starting dates that are after January 1 1980 and at least 18 years after date of birth.

I am able to get the random date of births generated but I am not sure how to use those to generate start dates that are after January 1 1980 and at least 18 years after birth.

```py
birthdates = []
import time

def strTimeProp(start, end, format, prop):
    """Get a time at a proportion of a range of two formatted times.
    start and end should be strings specifying times formated in the
    given format (strftime-style), giving an interval [start, end].
    prop specifies how a proportion of the interval to be taken after
    start.  The returned time will be in the specified format.
    """

    stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start, format))
    etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end, format))

    ptime = stime + prop * (etime - stime)
    return time.strftime(format, time.localtime(ptime))

def randomDate(start, end, prop):
    birthdates.append(strTimeProp(start, end, '%B %d %Y', prop))

for n in range(1000):
    randomDate("January 1 1960", "June 1 2001", random.random())
```

This creates a list of 1000 date of births in the format ['January 5 1974', ...], the second list I would like to create would be something along the lines of ['January 10, 1992', ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
birthdates = []
import time
import random

def strTimeProp(start, end, format, prop):
    """Get a time at a proportion of a range of two formatted times.
    start and end should be strings specifying times formated in the
    given format (strftime-style), giving an interval [start, end].
    prop specifies how a proportion of the interval to be taken after
    start.  The returned time will be in the specified format.
    """
    if len(start) == 6: 
        start = '0' + start[0] + '0' + start[1:]
    elif len(start) == 7: 
        start = '0' + start

    try:
        stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start, format))
    except:
        year = start[:-4]

        stime = time.mktime(time.strptime("February 28 " + year, format))
    etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end, format))

    ptime = stime + prop * (etime - stime)
    return time.strftime(format, time.localtime(ptime))

def randomDate(start, end, prop, list):
    list.append(strTimeProp(start, end, '%B %d %Y', prop))

for n in range(1000):
    randomDate("January 1 1960", "June 1 2001", random.random(), birthdates)

later_dates = []

for date in birthdates:
    month_day = date[:-4]
    year = date[-4:]
    randomDate(month_day + str(int(year) + 18), "June 1 2019", random.random(), later_dates)
```

The list `later_dates` will contain a list of the dates you want.

Comment: This sort of works, some times with larger numbers in the for loop I get this error ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: I fixed the bug.  Thanks for telling me about it.